# I created table in Postgresql which has 4 columns want to authenticate my login from this table of column 1 and 4 but it give c index out of rang

Tags: postgresql, jsp, jdbc, prepared-statement

The following code not working properly in my Servlet

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT uname,upass FROM shams WHERE uname=? and upass=? ");
ps.setString(1, name);
ps.setString(4, pass);
```

[image: This login not authenticated through database]

Comment: People won't click on your link to find what is behind it. Replace it with actual text. But, what does the "4" mean in your query code? You don't have four parameters to set.

Answer (score 1):

In `PreparedStatenent` SQL query parameters that are denoted with `?` are counted from `1` and there's no gap between indexes. When it's said that the parameter index is out of bounds then it means you have supplied wrong parameter value to the `setString()` method. Also note that parameters are counted from left to right in the SQL query consequently.

You should change

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("SELECT uname,upass FROM shams WHERE uname=? and upass=? "); 
ps.setString(1, name); 
ps.setString(2, pass);
```

---

Then read [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setString(int,%20java.lang.String)) about a method of setting parameters to SQL query.